# Vue 3: Imported CSS files render as a HTML javascript error in browser

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

I created a fresh Vue 3 app with vue-cli with Babel, ESlint, Prettier and no CSS pre-formatter. I try to load a .css file from the style tag of a component, but when I open it in the browser devtools I see an HTML document with the "please enable Javascript" error message.

Am I doing something wrong in my imports? The same import code worked fine with Vue 2.

Note that the CSS code works when I write it directly in the style tag rather than importing a separate file. It also works when I import it globally in the main.js of the Vue app. It just doesn't work when importing a separate file as exampled below.

Thank you for your help.

The App.vue from which I try to load a CSS file:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="__main-row" v-if="auth">
            <main class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
                <router-view />
            </main>
        </div>
        <div id="__main-row" v-else>
            <main>
                <router-view />
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        auth() {
            return this.$store.state.auth.user;
        }
    },

    watch: {
        $route() {
            this.$store.commit('alert/reset');
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style>
@import '/assets/css/main.css';
</style>
```

The CSS file when I open it in devtools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <title>vue-front</title>
    <link href="/js/about.js" rel="prefetch"><link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            <strong
                >We're sorry but vue-front doesn't
                work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
                continue.</strong
            >
        </noscript>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "vue-front",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "dev": "npm run serve & (cd api && npm run dev)"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "vue": "^3.0.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
        "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
            "eslint:recommended",
            "@vue/prettier"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": {}
    },
    "prettier": {
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "arrowParens": "always"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
    ]
}
```